# What is the correct way to listen to nested changes using Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

**Background:**

I'm trying to send SMS messages via the browser using Firebase, Twilio, and Node.js. My current data structure in Firebase looks like this:

```
{ messages :
  { +15553485 :
    { FB-GENERATED-KEY-1 :
      { body: "hello world"
        timestamp: 1461758765472 }
    },
    { FB-GENERATED-KEY-3 :
      { body: "I love dogs"
        timestamp: 1461758765475 }
      }
    }
  },
  { +15550000 :
    { FB-GENERATED-KEY-2 :
      { body: "goodbye world"
        timestamp: 1461758765473 }
    },
    { FB-GENERATED-KEY-4 :
      { body: "I love cats"
        timestamp: 1461758765476 }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When a message is added to Firebase via the frontend the backend needs to get notified in order to send an SMS via Twilio. When the backend gets a reply from the phone (via Twilio), it adds it to Firebase.

**Problems:**

When I listen for changes to a thread I receive all messages sent/recieved for that phone number. Obviously the backend doesn't want to send all the messages again, so I'm only interested in the most recent message added to the thread.

Also I can't seem to easily get the phone number (the key) that has messages underneath it.

**What I've tried:**

`ref.child('messages').on('child_added', ...)` — this works for new phone numbers that are added at `/messages`, however Firebase doesn't send through the new phone number (key), only everything from `FB-GENERATED-KEY-2` down.

`ref.child('messages').on('child_changed', ...)` — this returns *all* of the messages in a thread, not only the new ones. I can sort on the server and find the most recent message, but that seems like it'll get heavy quite quickly – what if you've sent thousands of messages?

Storing messages at the root level (aka. flattening the tree) and storing the number as an attribute instead could work, but I'm going to need to use the phone number as a sort of index to connect with other data later (like a foreign key).

**Questions:**

- How can I only get the most recent message when listening to activity on the parent `/messages` and not a particular phone number?
- How can I get the key (phone number) when using a `child_` event?
- Does this data structure make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Firebase key by calling [`key()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/key.html) on the snapshot returned by your `child_added` listener.

Then you can add another nested listener like this:

```
ref.child('messages').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var phone = snapshot.key();
    ref.child('messages').child(phone).on('child_added', function (message) {
        //send SMS
    }, function (error) {

    });
}, function (error) {

});
```

Comment: Ah! Of course it makes sense that `snapshot.val()` gives you the value and `snapshot.key()` gives you the key! Your answer should work well for when a new message is added with a new number, but what about when a new message is added for an existing number? Do I do a similar thing with nested listeners but with the `child_changed` event instead?

Comment: @BenjaminHumphrey Do you mean you already have an existing data set when you implement this? In this case I would maybe do something similar initially with `once('value')` in the outer listener. For new numbers, the inner listener will listen for ALL future new messages.

Comment: No, I mean when a new message is sent to a number that already exists in the database. The `child_added` event wouldn't fire at the top level because no new number was added, only a new message was added as a grandchild. However I've been reading more about structuring data in Firebase, and it sounds like I should flatten everything even further so /messages and /numbers are both at the root level. See [Structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html).

Comment: @BenjaminHumphrey If the outer `child_added` fired ONCE for a new number, the inner `child_added` will fire for EVERY new message for that number. Of course, a flattened data structure would make this case much easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase API allows you to listen for changes in value or for operations on children. It does not have a way to listen for changes in *grand*children.

In NoSQL databases you often need to model the data for the way your application uses it. If I look at your specific use-case:

> When a message is added to Firebase via the frontend the backend needs to get notified in order to send an SMS via Twilio.

I see a queue here:

```
smsQueue: {
  pushId1: {
    number: "+15553485",
    body: "hello world",
    timestamp: 1461758765472 
  },
  pushId2: {
    number: "+15550000",
    body: "goodbye world",
    timestamp: 1461758765473
  },
  pushId3: {
    number: "+15553485",
    body: "I love dogs",
    timestamp: 1461758765475
  },
  pushId4: {
    number: "+15550000",
    body: "I love cats",
    timestamp: 1461758765476 
  }
}
```

With this structure your back-end (which hopefully uses [firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue)) can take each task from the queue, call twilio and delete the item from the queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `firebase-queue` looks interesting, I'll check it out. However I do want to persist the messages in the database, so it's not quite the queue use-case you outlined.