# Firebase Realtime Database onChildChanged in subelements

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the configuration of my database

[image]

I'd like to use onChildChanged to look on each date child (and not on each date). Actually, with onChildChanged, it trigger when there is a modification in a date, and I must loop on every child of the date. Is there any other way?

In other words, instead of looking on each child of *request*, I'd like to watch each child of each child of *request*.

```
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            for (DataSnapshot dayRequest: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                // do stuff
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database `onChild*` events work on a list of child nodes.

If you attach a listener to `Requests` it will detect changes in the grandchildren that you have, but the event will fire with a `DataSnapshot` of a date (the immediate child nodes).

There is no way to use them to fire changes on the grandchild level. You will either have to figure out what grandchild has changed yourself, set up a listener on each date, or store the grandchildren in a single flat list and attach the listener there.

Also see:

- [How to tell which descendants are changed with on("child_changed")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161161/how-to-tell-which-descendants-are-changed-with-onchild-changed)
- [What is the correct way to listen to nested changes using Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892597)
- [how to watch for sub-child added event in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217878/how-to-watch-for-sub-child-added-event-in-firebase)
- [How can I observe Firebase child value changes in multiple nodes in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168993/how-can-i-observe-firebase-child-value-changes-in-multiple-nodes-in-swift)